# Proof of a sufficient condition for $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim _{n\to \infty }f'_{n}(x)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Wikipedia has the following theorem:

> If $(f_{n})$ is a sequence of differentiable functions on $[a,b]$ such that $\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }f_{n}(x_{0})$ exists (and is finite) for some $x_{0}\in [a,b]$ and the sequence $(f'_{n})$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then
> $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$, and $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim _{n\to \infty }f'_{n}(x)$ for $x\in [a,b]$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence

Can this theorem or a variant of it be proved from continuity?

The differentiation $f\mapsto f'$ is continuous from $\mathcal{C}^1([a,b])$ to $\mathcal{C}^0([a,b])$ with respect to the norm $\|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^1([a,b])}=\sup_{[a,b]}|f| + \sup_{[a,b]}|f'|$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/975785

I can see that if $f_n$ and $f’_n$ converges uniformly,
$\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim _{n\to \infty }f'_{n}(x)$ holds.

Comment: Write $f(x) = f(x_0)+ \int_{x_0}^x f'(t)dt$.